# Getting user and password authentication with javascript (Beginner)

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, authentication, token

I am studying Front End Development and am currently working on a project with 5 other colleagues. I have to implement the Login page. We also have to implement a Register and Logout page. This is how part of my html and the js code for the Login page looks like:

```
<script src="../models/Auth.js" type="text/javascript"></script>


<body>
  <div class="login-box">
    <h1>Login here</h1>
       <form>
        <p id ="Username">Username</p>
        <input type= "text"  placeholder = "Enter Username">

        <p id ="Password">Password</p>
        <input type= "password"  placeholder =" Enter Password">

        <input type="submit" id="submitButton" value ="Login">
            <a href="#"> Lost your password?</a><br>
            <a href="#"> Don't have an account?</a>
    </form>
</div>


(Javascript)

window.addEventListener("load",function (){
var username = document.getElementById("Username");
var password = document.getElementById("Password");
var submit=document.getElementById("submitButton");
var messageContainer=document.getElementById("Login");
var auth =new Auth();

submit.addEventListener("click",function ()

{

var username = document.getElementById("Username").value;
var password = document.getElementById("Password").value;

});
auth.Login();




auth.Login(username,password)
.then(function(response){
const token=response.accessToken;
auth.login(auth.Token);
auth.token=token;
document.cookie="accessToken="+token;
console.log(response.accessToken);
})
.catch(function(e) {
console.log(e) ;
loginContainer.innerHTML=e.status+ " You have to be registered in order to 
login";
});

});


function Auth(){
}
Auth.prototype.Login=function(Username, Password){
var root = 'https://ancient-caverns-16784.herokuapp.com';
return $.post(root+"/auth/login",{
username: 'test',
   password: 'test'
},
function(response) {
var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
console.log(xmlhttp);
xmlhttp.open("post", "Login", true);
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function () {
    if (xmlhttp.readyState == 401 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
        loginResults();
    }
 };
 console.log(response);
 });


 };
```

From what I understood, I only need to add the username and password into the Auth function. I am getting an error which says: auth.login is not a function. Am I missing something? I would appreciate any help provided.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

you have to enclose all the javascript code through its tag. For example:

```
<script>
window.addEventListener("load",function (){
var username = document.getElementById("Username");
var password = document.getElementById("Password");
var submit=document.getElementById("submitButton");
var messageContainer=document.getElementById("Login");
var auth =new Auth();

submit.addEventListener("click",function ()

{

var username = document.getElementById("Username").value;
var password = document.getElementById("Password").value;

});
auth.Login();




auth.Login(username,password)
.then(function(response){
const token=response.accessToken;
auth.login(auth.Token);
auth.token=token;
document.cookie="accessToken="+token;
console.log(response.accessToken);
})
.catch(function(e) {
console.log(e) ;
loginContainer.innerHTML=e.status+ " You have to be registered in order to 
login";
});

});


function Auth(){
}
Auth.prototype.Login=function(Username, Password){
var root = 'https://ancient-caverns-16784.herokuapp.com';
return $.post(root+"/auth/login",{
username: 'test',
   password: 'test'
},
function(response) {
var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
console.log(xmlhttp);
xmlhttp.open("post", "Login", true);
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function () {
    if (xmlhttp.readyState == 401 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
        loginResults();
    }
 };
 console.log(response);
 });


 };

</script>
```

Comment: The Javascript code is in another js file, I added a source at the beginning

Answer (score 0):

Password

```
    <input type="submit" id="submitButton" value ="Login">
        <a href="#"> Lost your password?</a><br>
        <a href="#"> Don't have an account?</a>
</form>
```